# How to force aspect ratio of subplot while keeping the width identical?

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I'm trying to create a plot with two subplots. 1 column, 2 rows.
Similar to the image but without the subplot to the right

How can I enforce one subplot to be square and the other one to have the same width without being square?

[image: from the seaborn gallery]

I tried gridspec without success:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.gridspec import GridSpec

fig = plt.figure(constrained_layout=True)

gs = GridSpec(nrows=4, ncols=3, height_ratios=[1, 1, 1, 1], figure=fig)
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[:-1,:])
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs[-1,:])
```

I also tried setting the aspect ratio for both subplots resulting in different widths the subplots:

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(2)
axs[0].set_aspect(1)
axs[1].set_aspect(2)
```

I also tried... but this fixes the x range of the subplots to the same value.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import ImageGrid

F = plt.figure()
grid = ImageGrid(F, 111,
                 nrows_ncols=(2, 1),
                 axes_pad=0.1,
                 )

grid[1].set_aspect(.4)
```

Thanks for any suggestions...

Comment: Several options. (1) Setting the aspect for both subplots, (2) Use a divider via `make_axes_locatable`, (3) Adjust the subplot parameters (or gridspec parameters) such that both axes are confined and one is square. I think all those exist as answers on SO already.

Answer (score 0):

One working solution I could come up with following the suggestions of ImportanceOfBeingErnest:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.axes_divider import make_axes_locatable

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,12))
axScatter = plt.subplot(111)
axScatter.set_aspect(1.)

divider = make_axes_locatable(axScatter)
axHistx = divider.append_axes("bottom", size=.8, pad=0.2)
```

Thank you!